# UPDATE SET = SELECT FROM

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update table based on a select query using this:

```
UPDATE branches SET name = 
(SELECT CONCAT(comp.name," ",bra.subsurb) as newname 
FROM companies comp 
RIGHT JOIN branches bra 
ON comp.id = bra.company_id)
```

Which, [according to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894302/mysql-update-table-set-column-select-count-from-select-from-table2-w), should work
but this produces an error: `You can't specify target table 'branches' for update in FROM clause`

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

EDIT:

Eventually this query did what I'm after:

`UPDATE branches bra LEFT JOIN companies comp 
ON comp.id = bra.company_id
SET bra.name = CONCAT(comp.name," ",bra.subsurb)`

Comment: Great minds think alike, you found the answer right while I posted it. ;P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error itself is pretty self explanatory, you are selecting from the table you are updating. Instead, you can use `JOIN` in the update statement. Try this:

```
UPDATE branches b
LEFT JOIN companies c ON c.id = b.company_id
SET b.name = CONCAT(c.name, " ", b.subsurb);
```

Note that because you're using a left join here to select all branches, regardless of whether or not they have a company, you may get null values for some names, so be careful about that.

Comment: Just tried this query before you write your answer and it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part.
This behaviour is documented at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

You will need to stop using the nested subquery and execute the operation in two parts, or alternatively use a simple where clause.

For more information please go through the following link

[MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is a restriction in MySQL.

To approach this problem, first write a `SELECT` statement that returns both the existing column value, and the new value you want to assign to the column:

e.g.

```
  SELECT b.company_id
       , b.name                       AS old_name
       , CONCAT(c.name,' ',b.subsurb) AS new_name
    FROM branches b
    LEFT
    JOIN companies c
      ON c.id = b.company_id
```

NOTE: beware of NULL values returned for `c.name` (possible because of the outer join). `CONCAT` including a NULL may return NULL.

Once that is returning the rows you want to update, convert that to an UPDATE by replacing the `SELECT ... FROM` with the keyword `UPDATE`, and add a `SET` clause immediately before the `WHERE` clause:

```
  UPDATE branches b
    LEFT
    JOIN companies c
      ON c.id = b.company_id
     SET b.name = CONCAT(c.name,' ',b.subsurb)
```